# Erreur vs faute

Tags: usage, choix-de-mot

Je crois que dans la langue courante, les termes "erreur" et "faute" sont souvent utilisés de manière interchangeable, mais ils peuvent avoir des nuances de sens différentes selon le contexte.

Quand est-il correct de les utiliser de manière interchangeable et quand doit-on employer l'un et pas l'autre?

Les différences sont-elles les mêmes que pour la paire "error/mistake"?

Comment: Pour moi ces mots ne sont pas vraiment interchangeables. L'erreur est faite par inadvertance, la faute peut être volontaire ou involontaire, et c'est toujours la transgression d'une règle, il y a une valeur / un jugement moral(e) dans l'emploi du mot faute qu'on ne trouve dans le mot erreur. Il est probable que si nous commencions ici une discussion sur « faute d'orthographe » (expression reçue) ou « erreur d'orthographe » on discuterait longtemps en campant sur nos positions. If any comparison with English, I'd say *erreur* is closer to "mistake".

Comment: Un article qui montre que le sujet est vaste, autant linguistique que philosophique :[Pourquoi peut-on dire être en faute , être dans l’erreur mais non * être dans la faute , * être en erreur ?](https://www.cairn.info/revue-langue-francaise-2013-2-page-81.htm)

Comment: Pouvez-vous nous préciser la différence error/mistake ? Que disent les dictionnaires sur la différence erreur/ faute ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

L'erreur aussi bien que la faute désignent le fait de se tromper, ce n'est cependant pas pour autant que les deux mots sont interchangeables, même si dans la langue courante certains emplois du mot *faute* peuvent conduire à le penser.

Selon le *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* (extraits) :

- **Erreur**

> du latin *erroris* : « action d'errer ça et là » et par figure incertitude, ignorance, d'où méprise, illusion. (...) Le mot se dit dès l'ancien français d'une action regrettable, maladroite et spécialement d'un écart de conduite. (...) Courant dans ***erreur judiciaire*** il prend dans l'usage général le sens d'« inexactitude, faute », d'où *par erreur* « en se trompant par ignorance, par étourderie » et des emplois particulier en physique (*erreur relative, erreur absolue*).

- **Faute**

> du latin *fallita*, action de faillir. (...) La *faute* désigne d'abord le fait de manquer aux prescriptions religieuses. (...) Par
> extension, *faute*, désigne en général le manquement à une règle (...).

En regardant l'étymologie des deux mots on voit que l'***erreur*** est toujours faite par inadvertance et que si  la ***faute*** peut être volontaire ou involontaire, c'est toujours la transgression d'une règle.  Il y a une valeur / un jugement moral(e) dans l'emploi du mot *faute* qu'on ne trouve pas dans le mot *erreur*.

Si je dis à un enfant qui a écrit  †*les chiens joues dans le jardin*  qu'il a fait une faute, je me mets dans une posture de jugement en mettant l'accent sur la transgression d'une règle de conjugaison. Si je lui dis qu'il a fait une erreur, je mets l'accent sur son étourderie, je peux donc sous-entendre qu'il connait la règle mais qu'il l'a momentanément oubliée.

En français nous avons l'expression « avoir le droit à l'erreur », en pédagogie on dit qu'« on apprend de ses erreurs », apprendre de ses erreurs constitue une étape de l'apprentissage.

Bien sûr il y a des bizarreries de la langue, on parle le plus souvent de « faute d'orthographe » mais d'« erreur de calcul » comme si se tromper sur les lettres était plus grave que se tromper sur les nombres !!

Dans certains domaines il est important de bien différencier la faute et l'erreur. C'est le cas en particulier en droit, [voir le dictionnaire du droit privé](https://www.dictionnaire-juridique.com/index.php) :

> La "faute" est l'action volontaire ou non, ou encore l'omission qui porte atteinte au droit d'autrui en lui causant un dommage.

> L'"erreur" est une "méprise". Le droit s'intéresse à l'erreur soit pour la rectifier soit pour en tirer des conséquences sur la validité de l'acte qui en est entaché.

ou encore en médecine ([sur le site d'un cabinet d'avocats](https://www.arcadioavocats.fr/actualites/quelle-difference-entre-erreur-medicale-et-faute-medicale,135)):

> Puisque l’erreur est humaine, et que les médecins aussi, il est donc possible pour un médecin de commettre une erreur, sans qu’il soit pour autant juste de l’accuser de faute.

> La différence entre erreur médicale et faute médicale tient en premier lieu à l’existence de règles applicables au domaine médical, que tout praticien est tenu de respecter : le non-respect de ces règles permet donc d’établir la faute.

L'article [Pourquoi peut-on dire être en faute, être dans l'erreur mais non *être dans la faute, *être en erreur ?](https://www.cairn.info/revue-langue-francaise-2013-2-page-81.htm)<sup>1</sup> montre que le débat sur *faute* et *erreur* est autant philosophique que linguistique. J'en cite un passage :

> Si *erreur* et *faute* ont formellement et sémantiquement en commun de pouvoir exprimer une action (fait qui suppose un agent), mais *erreur* plus volontiers que *faute* (...), les deux noms s’opposent en ce que *erreur* (mais non *faute*) peut en outre désigner un événement fortuit, tandis que *faute* (mais non *erreur*) est susceptible d’indiquer de surcroît un affect – en l’occurrence l’émotion (négative) ressentie à l’idée d’avoir commis une erreur, interprété comme le fait d’avoir failli, facteur de culpabilité. Les deux termes désignent donc deux situations successives, puisque c’est la prise de conscience d’avoir commis une erreur qui engendre un sentiment de faute.
> L’erreur est (linguistiquement) fortuite en ceci qu’elle n’incrimine pas la responsabilité de son auteur (l’un des stéréotypes de *erreur* est d’ailleurs qu’elle est inhérente à l’espèce humaine) ; qui plus est susceptible d’être explicitement attribuée à un facteur extérieur à la personne, comme le montre l’expression quasi-figée *induire en erreur* (**induire en faute*), elle pèse d’autant moins sur l’individu seul qu’elle peut se propager, se répandre – ce qui n’est pas le cas de la faute. À l’opposé, la faute est liée à la responsabilité de celui qui la commet, comme en témoigne l’accusation qui incrimine directement son auteur *C’est (de) ma faute, C’est (de) sa faute*, etc. – distribution impossible pour *erreur*. La faute pèse sur son auteur, mais des formulations parallèles comme *poids de l’erreur*, *poids des erreurs*, *poids de mon (mes) erreur(s)* ne sont pas couramment représentées.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>Danielle Leeman in *Langue française* 2013/2 (n°178).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Dans les commentaires de @None :

Pour moi ces mots ne sont pas vraiment interchangeables. L'erreur est faite par inadvertance, la faute peut être volontaire ou involontaire, et c'est toujours la transgression d'une règle, il y a une valeur / un jugement moral(e) dans l'emploi du mot faute qu'on ne trouve dans le mot erreur.

Il est probable que si nous commencions ici une discussion sur « faute d'orthographe » (expression reçue) ou « erreur d'orthographe » on discuterait longtemps en campant sur nos positions. If any comparison with English, I'd say erreur is closer to "mistake".

Un article qui montre que le sujet est vaste, autant linguistique que philosophique :[Pourquoi peut-on dire être en faute , être dans l’erreur mais non * être dans la faute , * être en erreur ?](https://www.cairn.info/revue-langue-francaise-2013-2-page-81.htm)

Comment: Merci pour avoir mis en avant mon commentaire (rédigé à la va-vite), j'ai cependant une réponse un peu plus étoffée à proposer. Que faire ? Je rédige une autre réponse où je reprendrai de toutes façons ce que je dis en commentaire ou tu transformes en wiki ? As you like it....

Comment: Effectivement on dirait que la différence semble plus dans le jugement porté sur l'action que sur la nature de l'action elle-même. Intéressant.

Comment: @XouDo Et cette première impression est confirmée par l'étymologie et certains emplois spécifiques. Je vais développer mais pas en commentaire ! (trop long)

Comment: Vas-y réponds. Comme tes commentaires donnent déjà une bonne réponse je voulais garder l'explication et le liens au moins.  Pardon je savais pas que tu pensais toujours écrire de plus comme c'était que des commentaires.

Comment: Pas la peine de t'excuser, tu pouvais pas deviner ! Le commentaire est un peu léger et je tenais à développer.

Comment: Mais il s'agit des *fautes*, c'est trop con !  Confiteor : oui j'ai vraiment péché.

Answer (score 1):

En informatique, nous faisons ces distinctions.

Le programmeur commet une **erreur** (un mauvais raisonnement, par exemple)
et alors, en écrivant une ligne de code fausse, son logiciel a un **défaut**.

Lors de son exécution, le programme qu'il a écrit
tombe sur l'instruction erronée et commet une **faute**.
Et si celle-ci n'est pas rattrapée (si le système n'est pas, comme on dit, tolérant aux fautes)
l'application se met **en panne**.

Comment: La "tolérance au fautes" d'un système informatique concerne très rarement les instructions erronées dues à des erreurs de programmation mais plutôt les erreurs dues à des problèmes électriques, interférences, pannes, etc pour lesquelles une identification et une solution de repli sont plus facilement envisageables.

Comment: @jlliagre C'est juste. Mais en génie logiciel, d'où vient cette définition, ils généralisent.

Comment: Qui ils ? Il faudrait que tu donnes des exemples, des citations. On est quand même dans un domaine très spécifique. En informatique, quand on parle de *fault tolerant*, c'est rarement pour contrecarrer des bugs logiciels, mais je me répète.

Comment: @jlliagre Pour t'illustrer la validité, l'acuité de la notion de tolérance aux fautes d'un point de vue logiciel, de la programmation, c'est très simple. Une application dont les anomalies sont prises en charge (par une gestion d'exceptions, par exemple), passera une situation où elle a un bug, même si elle ne résout pas l'incident. Une application qui ne le fera pas, pourra être stoppée par le bug en question: le programme se terminera (avec un message d'erreur ou pas), se gèlera, etc. Cette tolérance aux fautes mise en place par des exceptions est une bonne pratique de programmation.

Comment: Ok, je vois à quoi tu fais allusion mais je n'ai jamais entendu personne dire qu'un programme "commet une faute" dans le cas que tu cites. On dira plutôt qu'il [lève une exception](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/lever_une_exception), et les exceptions ne sont pas toutes nécessairement dues à des erreurs de programmation. Elles peuvent faire partie du fonctionnement normal d'un programme.

Comment: Il existe bien des "fautes" comme une division par zéro, le déréférencement d'un pointeur nul, un accès mémoire à une adresse absente de la mémoire physique mais j'ai surtout entendu l'anglais *fault* dans ces cas là, comme dans *page fault* par exemple.